# JSONPath in Javascript is so long - About 3000 times longer than a classic loop

Tags: javascript, json, performance, jsonpath

I have **got performance issues with JSONPath run in Javascript** (with [Stephan Goessner Usefull Library](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/))

With the following JSON structure.

```
[
    {
    id:1, 
    name: "lorem", 
    elements: 
    [
        {
            id:101,
            date: Fri Jan 31 2014 18:03:41 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid),  // Javascript Date Object,
            instances: [ 
                {
                    id: 1001, 
                    properties: [
                        {
                            code: 'ipsum lens', 
                            id: 1001, 
                            values: [
                                "value1", 
                                "value2",
                                ...
                                // less than 5 values
                            ]
                        }, 
                        ... , / between 20 to 40 items
                    ]
                },
                ... // About 100 items
            ]
        },
        ... // Less than 5 items
    ], 
    meta: [
        {
            id: 10000, 
            code: 'codeabc', 
            property1: true, 
            property2: false,
            property3: 2939, 
        }, 
        ... // between 20 to 40 items
    ]
    }, 
    ... // 4 items
]
```

Here are **quantities** :

- level1 contains 4 items
- level2 'elements' contains 2 items on each level
- level3 'instances' contains about 100 items on my specific element (other are quite the same)
- level4 'properties' contains about 15 items

With **JSON path**, following code give me a **response time closed to 4 seconds** in chrome

```
var startDate = new Date();
var searchedValue = jsonPath(
    myJSONStore, 
    "$.[?(@.name == 'myelementname')].elements[?(@.id == 100)].date"
)[0];
console.log(date)
console.log("Get in " + ((new Date().getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000) + "s")
```

I found this delay really long, considering the low data quantity. 
**I tried also this classic code, without jsonPath**

```
var startDate = new Date();
var searchedValue = null;
for(i in myJSONStore) { 
    if (myJSONStore[i].name == 'myelementname') { 
        for (j in myJSONStore[i].elements) {
            if (myJSONStore[i].elements[j].id == 100) {
                var date = myJSONStore[i].elements[j].date;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(date)
console.log("Get in " + ((new Date().getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000) + "s")
```

This time, **it tooks ONLY 1 milliseconds**.

JsonPath keeps his attractivity because of his simple and short syntax (like in [kiss principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), I'm addict of)... but is there a way to **reduce calculation delay** ... ? about **4000 times more is quite impressive**

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSONPath, but are you sure it's not searching through your whole dataset?

Comment: maybe yes, but jsonpath is built with low level eval javascript function ... a bit hard to review

JSonPath is built to find several results. In my particular cas, I need only one result... maybe a fix could be found ... 

I've contacted the author... keep in touch

Answer (score -1):

1)Use below code in aspx.cs page.

string path= "Your JSON file path";
Hiddenfield.Value = File.ReadAllText(path);

2) After that,try using below code in aspx page,i.e getting json object through hidden field.

var xyz =$.parseJSON(document.getElementById('<%=Hiddenfield.ClientID%>').value);

Comment: Hi aakash, I can not use asp code. 
In my app, i have to run all of that in pure javascript. That is why i use this implementation, made by Stefan Goessner